# Как изменять html код с помощью php?

Tags: php, html

Есть титульная страница сайта, при проверке на существование `$_SESSION['user']` нужно менять header на титульной странице (*если **$_SESSION['user']** существует*).

Как можно это сделать?

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Savan Logistics</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/pngegg.png" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="login.php" class="menu-link">Войти</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="registration.php" class="menu-link">Регистрация</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="index.php" class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Логотип сайта" class="logo-img" />
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
      <section class="headline">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="title">ТРАНСПОРТНАЯ КОМПАНИЯ</h1>
          <img src="images/truck.png" alt="ГРУЗОВИК" class="headline-img" />
          <a href="#chooseDelivery" class="headline-btn">ВЫБРАТЬ ДОСТАВКУ</a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="about">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="about-title">О НАС</h2>
          <div class="about-info">
            <div class="about-text">
              <p>
                Молодая, активно развивающаяся компания, которая оказывает
                услуги по перевозке грузов автомобильным транспортом.
              </p>
              <p>
                Транспортная компания решала задачи по грузоперевозкам
                всевозможной сложности, решения для которых находилось всегда
                оперативно и имело адекватную ценовую политику. Главная причина,
                по которой компании удается достигать таких высоких результатов
                на рынке грузоперевозок - это, в первую очередь, наличие своего
                современного парка автомобилей, позволяющего выполнять перевозки
                (грузоперевозки) различной сложности, далеко не все транспортные
                компании могут позволить себе такую роскошь. Автомобильный парк
                транспортной компании укомплектован автомобилями ведущих мировых
                производителей и отвечает всем европейским стандартам.
              </p>
              <b>
                Фирма располагает самыми высококвалифицированными и опытными
                сотрудниками, а также необходимым техническим оборудованием. Это
                позволяет компании предоставлять только надежные, качественные и
                оперативные услуги грузоперевозок.
              </b>
            </div>
            <img class="images-about" src="images/woman.png" alt="about" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="delivery">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 id="chooseDelivery" class="delivery-title">ВЫБЕРИТЕ ДОСТАВКУ</h2>
            <ul class="delivery-list">
                <a href="#" class="smallBox-btn">
                <li class="delivery-item">
                <img src="images/smallBox.png" alt="Малая" />
                <h3>Малая</h3>
                <p>До 10 кг</p>
              </li>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="middleBox-btn">
              <li class="delivery-item">
                <img src="images/middleBox.png" alt="Средняя" />
                <h3>Средняя</h3>
                <p>До 30 кг</p>
              </li>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="bigBox-btn">
              <li class="delivery-item">
                <img src="images/bigBox.png" alt="Большая" />
                <h3>Большая</h3>
                <p>До 60 кг</p>
              </li>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="veryBigBox-btn">
              <li class="delivery-item">
                <img src="images/veryBigBox.png" alt="Очень большая" />
                <h3>Big большая</h3>
                <p>Свыше 60 кг</p>
              </li>
              </a>
            </ul> 
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="contacts">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="contacts-inner">
            <form class="contacts-form" action="#">
              <h2 class="contacts-title">ХОТИТЕ СВЯЗАТЬСЯ С НАМИ?</h2>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="contacts-input"
                placeholder="Ваше имя"
              />
              <input
                type="tel"
                class="contacts-input"
                placeholder="Номер телефона"
              />
              <p>В ближайшее время наш менеджер свяжется с Вами</p>
              <button type="submit">СВЯЗАТЬСЯ</button>
            </form>
            <img class="contacts-img" src="images/trucks.jpg" alt="iphone" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-inner">
                <a target="_blank" class="footer-link" href="https://vk.com/ruslanrttd">
                  <img src="images/vkLogo.png" alt="Логотип ВК">
                </a>
                <img class="logo-img" src="images/logo.png" alt="Логотип сайта">
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Вот так сделал, ругается при первом же упоминании html:

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Savan Logistics</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/pngegg.png" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if ($_SESSION['user']){
        <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
          <nav class="nav">
            <button class="menuBtn" id="burger">
              <span></span><span></span><span></span>
            </button>
            <div class="burgerMenu">
              <ul class="menuList">
                <li class="menuItem">
                  <a href="#" class="menuRef">
                    Личный кабинет
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuItem">
                  <a href="#" class="menuRef">
                    Заказать доставку
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menuItem">
                  <a href="#" class="menuRef">
                    Безопасность
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="index.php" class="logo">
              <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Логотип сайта" class="logo-img" />
            </a>
            <a href="include/logout.php" class="exit"><img src="images/exit.png" alt="Выход"></a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      }
      else{
        <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="login.php" class="menu-link">Войти</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="registration.php" class="menu-link">Регистрация</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="index.php" class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Логотип сайта" class="logo-img" />
          </a>
          <a href="tel:79512010730" class="phone">+7(951)201-07-30</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: if ($_SESSION[]) { ?> HTML КОД <?php } else { ?> HTML КОД <? } - как то так...

Comment: а какие-то метки кода html надо прописывать в if'е?

Comment: @РусланАсадуллин метки?

Comment: На сколько помню(я пхп не трогал лет так много), просто внутрь хпх условия добавляете нужный html код и все.

Comment: в посте дополнил что сделал

Comment: Не забывайте про открывающие и закрывающие теги, то чем Вы дополнили вопрос, работать не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выводить тот или иной HTML код по условию:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />    
  <? if($_SESSION['user']): ?>
    <title>Вы авторизованы</title>
  <? else: ?>
    <title>Вы НЕ авторизованы</title>  
  <? endif; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Просто в нужном месте HTML разметки добавляем PHP код и определяем, что должно выводиться в том или ином случае.

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Руки чешутся отформатировать код))

Comment: @De.Minov Отформатируйте ) У меня под рукой нет подходящего редактора...

Comment: @SwaD, если вы про PHPstorm, то он мне не понравился, да и PHP очень редко юзаю. Да и данный вариант запили условий `if():`, `else:` и `endif;` мне кажется более читабельный, чем с фигурными скобками. Да и `<?php` уже давно не всегда можно писать :)

Comment: @De.Minov Я php трогал последний раз более 10 лет назад и то, по мелочи. Просто помню, как там выодятся теги по условию )